# What javascript module api does duojs use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, component.io, duo.js

I'm using [duojs](https://github.com/duojs/duo), which is a front-end webdevelopment tool not unlike browserify or component. It allows you to import css and js straight from the file itself, without any external package manifests.

I'm trying to understand how to write my js so it works well with duojs, but am not sure what kind of architecture it uses for its module definitions. I've looked for it in the documentation, but couldn't find it there. From what I can tell it looks like the duojs compiler wraps all components in commonjs style wrappers:

See for example [this compiled js file on their repo](https://github.com/duojs/duojs.org/blob/gh-pages/build/index.js) (below is a snippet):

```
 /**
* Return newest require.
*/
return require;
})({
1: [function(require, module, exports) {
/**
* Module Dependencies
*/
var Highlight = require('segmentio/highlight');
/**
* Code highlighting.
*/
new Highlight()
.use(require('segmentio/highlight-javascript'))
.use(require('segmentio/highlight-xml'))
.use(require('segmentio/highlight-css'))
.use(require('segmentio/highlight-json'))
.all();
```

Can anyone tell from the code what kind of js module api is being used here? To me this looks like a commonjs style module definition, but I'm not sure, it might be node as well.

Comment: it looks like a "duojs" kind of module.  why do you need to categorize it as being some other thing?  perhaps rephrase the question to express your actual goal

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "what kind of js module api". As Robert said, your actual purpose isn't communicated usefully here.

Comment: @RobertLevy, Yeah I'm sorry, I don't know exactly what to call it. What I'm trying to understand is what kind of modules duo can consume. AMD or CommonJS, or something else. Does that make sense?

Comment: @sphanley, What I'm trying to understand is what kind of modules duo can consume: AMD, CommonJS or something else. Could you suggest a way to better phrase this question? I don't really know what to call it.

Comment: The duoJS documentation says "To get started just write normal Javascript". There's no indication you're supposed to write in any "module format" - you just write JavaScript and DuoJS will bundle it into its own format. Your question just doesn't make sense because asking what module format you're supposed to use presupposes that there's a module format required to begin with.

Comment: @sphanley, Yes, I've read that. But did you take a look at the generated file that I linked to? Duo wraps the code in what seems like a module format (commonJS I believe). That's not just a normal concatenation of js.

Comment: But why are you trying to write the module manually? Isn't the point of DuoJS that it loads your normal JS into a module itself? I'm totally open to the idea that I'm not understanding this - I just don't see what's making you think that you have to write the module.

Comment: @sphanley, Well to quote my question: *I'm trying to understand how to write my js so it works well with duojs, but am not sure what kind of architecture it uses for its module definitions*. So I'm just trying to understand whether it wraps my code with commonJS, AMD, or something else. Because `var $ = require('jquery/jquery');` isn't vanilla javascript, but you can still use it with duojs. So there's something other than vanilla js going on there. I'm simply trying to understand what that 'something other' is, so I can read up on it.

Comment: I don't understand, the question isn't that weird is it? And I'd appreciate it if people told me why they're downvoting so that I can make a change. Just suggest something instead of downvoting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duo uses [duo-pack](https://github.com/duojs/pack) to build it's javascript. duo-pack's javascript packer is very similar to browserify's [browser-pack](https://github.com/substack/browser-pack). duo-pack differs in that it also supports packing CSS.

It's packed in such a way that the entry file will get executed immediately when the script is included.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, and from what I've found, it doesn't use another API structure.  Check out https://github.com/duojs/duo/blob/master/docs/api.md for information about how-to use the DuoJS API.

To my eye, it appears that it is entirely built from scratch, but I'm not an expert in any form of JavaScript.